# paypal buttons - is it possible to have a discounted price if 3 items are purchased

Tags: paypal

I want to make a page with the same item but with multiple patterns. they are all the same price but if you order 3 i want a discounted price.

ie
item 1  blue - 10.00
item 2  flowers - 10.00
item 3  ballons - 10.00

so if someone orders 2 number 1's and a number 3 instead of 30.00 they would pay 25.00

it can not be a generic total cart discount, it would only apply to a select group of items

is this possible or do i need to write some js?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of the `discount_amount` , `discount_amount2` and `discount_num` tags to support tiered discounts, here's a sample for your scenario:

single item price is $10 with no discount `discount_amount=0`, when you add each additional quantity of the item to the cart, a discount of $5 will apply `discount_amount2=5`, so that you pay $5 for the 2nd, 3rd, .. item, until you've added up to 10 additional items (upper limit) `discount_num=10`

Try the codes below and customize with your own logic,

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" value="_cart" name="cmd">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="add">
  <input type="hidden" value="usm@email.com" name="business">
  <input type="hidden" value="sale" name="paymentaction">
  <input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
  <p>
    ItemName No.1 (Regular Price $10.00):
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ItemName No.1">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
  </p>

  <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount2" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" name="discount_num" value="10">

  <input type="hidden" value="http://lychee-vip.ccg21.dev.paypalcorp.com/" name="return">
  <input type="image" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" name="submit" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif">
</form>
```

Comment: i get that part, but i need it for if someone buy 1 of 3 different items they get a discount.

Comment: Current button form tags don't support cross-item specific discounts, you'll need some JS for cart level subtotal calculation before submitting to PayPal